# Go error in YouCompleteMe Compilation VIM

Tags: go, vim, cmake, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I'm new in VIM, and I tried to install YouCompleteMe plugin with VimPlug... But when I start `python3 install.py --all` But after, I got this error:

```
# golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/analysis/fillstruct
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/lsp/analysis/fillstruct/fillstruct.go:141:14: tok.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/lsp/analysis/fillstruct/fillstruct.go:170:15: tok.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/lsp/analysis/fillstruct/fillstruct.go:172:15: tok.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
# golang.org/x/tools/internal/jsonrpc2
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/jsonrpc2/messages.go:171:5: undefined: errors.As
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/jsonrpc2/serve.go:129:5: undefined: errors.Is
```

And I don't know what it mean?
There Are complete logs:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.7.so (found suitable version "3.7.3", minimum required is "3.5") 
-- Using libclang archive: /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/cpp/../clang_archives/libclang-10.0.0-armv7a-linux-gnueabihf.tar.bz2
-- Using libclang to provide semantic completion for C/C++/ObjC
-- Using external libclang: /tmp/ycm_build_zcxr6q5l/lib/libclang.so.10
-- NOT using clang-tidy for static analysis.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/ycm_build_zcxr6q5l
Scanning dependencies of target BoostParts
[  2%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/codecvt_error_category.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/directory.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/exception.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/path_traits.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/portability.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/unique_path.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.cpp.o
[ 30%] Linking CXX static library libBoostParts.a
[ 30%] Built target BoostParts
Scanning dependencies of target ycm_core
[ 33%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Candidate.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CandidateRepository.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Character.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CharacterRepository.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/ClangCompleter.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/ClangHelpers.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/ClangUtils.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/CompilationDatabase.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/CompletionData.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/Documentation.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/Range.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/TranslationUnit.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ClangCompleter/TranslationUnitStore.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CodePoint.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CodePointRepository.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierDatabase.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierUtils.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Result.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Utils.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Word.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/versioning.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so
[100%] Built target ycm_core
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.7.so (found version "3.7.3") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/regex_build_x5t1av6p
Scanning dependencies of target _regex
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/_regex.dir/regex_3/_regex.c.o
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/_regex.dir/regex_3/_regex_unicode.c.o
[100%] Linking C shared library /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/cregex/regex_3/_regex.so
[100%] Built target _regex
running build
running build_py
creating /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3
creating /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog
copying src/watchdog/events.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog
copying src/watchdog/watchmedo.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog
copying src/watchdog/__init__.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog
copying src/watchdog/version.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog
creating /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
copying src/watchdog/utils/compat.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
copying src/watchdog/utils/win32stat.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
copying src/watchdog/utils/dirsnapshot.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
copying src/watchdog/utils/delayed_queue.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
copying src/watchdog/utils/echo.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
copying src/watchdog/utils/bricks.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
copying src/watchdog/utils/unicode_paths.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
copying src/watchdog/utils/__init__.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
copying src/watchdog/utils/platform.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/utils
creating /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/tricks
copying src/watchdog/tricks/__init__.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/tricks
creating /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/inotify_c.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/inotify_buffer.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/fsevents.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/polling.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/inotify.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/api.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/read_directory_changes.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/kqueue.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/__init__.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/fsevents2.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
copying src/watchdog/observers/winapi.py -> /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/watchdog_deps/watchdog/build/lib3/watchdog/observers
running egg_info
writing src/watchdog.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src/watchdog.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to src/watchdog.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing requirements to src/watchdog.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to src/watchdog.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src/watchdog.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'src'
writing manifest file 'src/watchdog.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Searching Python 3.7 libraries...
Found Python library: /usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.7.so
Found Python headers folder: /usr/include/python3.7m
Installing Omnisharp v1.35.3
Using cached Omnisharp: omnisharp.http-linux-x86.tar.gz
Extracting Omnisharp to /home/pi/.vim/plugged/youcompleteme/third_party/ycmd/third_party/omnisharp-roslyn...DONE
Done installing Omnisharp
go: finding github.com/kr/pty v1.1.1
go: finding golang.org/x/mod v0.0.0-20190513183733-4bf6d317e70e
go: finding gopkg.in/errgo.v2 v2.1.0
go: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f
go: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20191130070609-6e064ea0cf2d
go: finding golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190510104115-cbcb75029529
go: finding gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20180628173108-788fd7840127
go: finding golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190404232315-eb5bcb51f2a3
go: finding golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190412213103-97732733099d
go: finding golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190308221718-c2843e01d9a2
go: finding golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190215142949-d0b11bdaac8a
go: finding golang.org/x/text v0.3.0
go: finding golang.org/x/mod v0.2.0
go: finding golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200226121028-0de0cce0169b
go: finding golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190620200207-3b0461eec859
go: finding github.com/yuin/goldmark v1.1.27
go: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20191119224855-298f0cb1881e
go: finding golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20191011191535-87dc89f01550
go: finding golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543
go: finding golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20190717185122-a985d3407aa7
go: finding golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191011141410-1b5146add898
go: finding golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20190911185100-cd5d95a43a6e
go: finding golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20190423024810-112230192c58
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.4.2
go: downloading honnef.co/go/tools v0.0.1-2020.1.4
go: downloading github.com/sergi/go-diff v1.1.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543
go: downloading mvdan.cc/xurls/v2 v2.2.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20190911185100-cd5d95a43a6e
go: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.2.0
go: downloading github.com/BurntSushi/toml v0.3.1
# golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/analysis/fillstruct
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/lsp/analysis/fillstruct/fillstruct.go:141:14: tok.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/lsp/analysis/fillstruct/fillstruct.go:170:15: tok.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/lsp/analysis/fillstruct/fillstruct.go:172:15: tok.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
# golang.org/x/tools/internal/jsonrpc2
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/jsonrpc2/messages.go:171:5: undefined: errors.As
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200701133321-6ddc6be4d35f/internal/jsonrpc2/serve.go:129:5: undefined: errors.Is
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your Go version, it is too old. `errors.As` was introduced in Go 1.13.